# Mysql select in variable

Tags: mysql

I need a query like this.

```
Set @var1:="30,31";
Select * from mytable where id in (@var)
```

I've tried on more tables,
but MySQL returns null value.
Why?

Comment: Because @var1 is a varchar variable and not a list of values.

Comment: Not that it matters but you are testing @VAR which you haven't set up.

Comment: Have you checked for obvious typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `find_in_set()` check [Here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

```
SET @var1 = "30,31";
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE find_in_set(myTable.myColumn, @var1);
```

MySQL return `NULL` value because search string and not a list of values

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic SQL to do this.  Prepared statements are one general way to go, except that binding an unknown number of values to a `WHERE IN` clause is difficult.  Assuming you always would be binding only two values, we can try:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?, ?)';
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
SET @var1 = 30;
SET @var2 = 31;
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @var1, @var2;
```